# Adding Ghostscript to Clickonce prerequisites

Tags: clickonce, ghostscript

My VB.NET application, which I distribute via ClickOnce, uses Josip Habjan Ghostscript.NET to renderize Pdfs, a managed wrapper library around GPL Ghostscript which needs to be installed on the client machine.
As it does not appear on my project prerequisites checklist, is there anyway to have it installed along within the clickonce process?

Comment: Maybe this article will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15863/Add-your-own-custom-prerequisite-to-quot-ClickOnce

Comment: Thanks Habjan, and congrats for your Ghostscript.NET component. The link asks to download the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator from GotDotNet on a broken link since it was moved to Codeplex when GotDotNet was phased out, but Codeplex is no longer hosting it. Do you know where can I download it from?